# Terratest multiple targets

Tags: go, terraform, terratest

I am using terrates to test my terraform code.
My code have 2 modules so I managed to configure terratest to use target option while configuring the terraformOptions and it creates both modules.

However, when it comes to clean everything, it cleans only the last module using Defer.
Here is my code.

```
    package test

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "testing"

    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"

    test_structure "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/test-structure"
)

func configureTerraformOptions(t *testing.T, terraformDir string, tfModule string) (*terraform.Options) {

    awsRegion := os.Getenv("AWS_REGION")

    terraformOptions := &terraform.Options{

        TerraformDir: terraformDir,
        Targets: []string{tfModule},
        Vars: map[string]interface{}{
            "aws_region": awsRegion,
        },
    }

    return terraformOptions

}

func TestInfra(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()

    terraformDir := test_structure.CopyTerraformFolderToTemp(t, "../", "tests/terraform")

    defer test_structure.RunTestStage(t, "destroy", func() {
        terraformOptions := test_structure.LoadTerraformOptions(t, terraformDir)
        terraform.Destroy(t, terraformOptions)

    })

    test_structure.RunTestStage(t, "setup", func() {
        terraformOptionsInfra := configureTerraformOptions(t, terraformDir, "module.one")
        terraformOptionsConf := configureTerraformOptions(t, terraformDir, "module.two")

        test_structure.SaveTerraformOptions(t, terraformDir, terraformOptionsInfra)

        test_structure.SaveTerraformOptions(t, terraformDir, terraformOptionsConf)

        terraform.InitAndApply(t, terraformOptionsInfra)
        terraform.InitAndApply(t, terraformOptionsConf)
    })
    test_structure.RunTestStage(t, "validate", func() {
        terraformOptions := test_structure.LoadTerraformOptions(t, terraformDir)
        testHello(t, terraformOptions)

    })
}

func testHello(t *testing.T, terraformOptions *terraform.Options) {
   fmt.Printf("Hello")
}
```

Is there any way to target like when I apply ?

Thanks;

Answer (score 3):

I think there are a couple issues here:

1. In the `setup` step, you're calling `SaveTerraformOptions` twice, but what you have to realize is that the second call is overwriting the first one!
2. In the `destroy` step, you call `LoadTerraformOptions` and `Destroy` just once, so even if you had both `terraform.Options` structs, you'd still only be running `destroy` on one of them.

I think to fix this, in the `setup` step, you'll to call [SaveTestData](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/e323e9ffa190d559a0d7b048fa735945ec4d1cf9/modules/test-structure/save_test_data.go#L167) directly (`SaveTerraformOptions` is just a wrapper for this method) with different paths:

```
test_structure.SaveTestData(t, test_structure.FormatTestDataPath(terraformDir, "TerraformOptionsInfra.json"), terraformOptionsInfra)
test_structure.SaveTestData(t, test_structure.FormatTestDataPath(terraformDir, "TerraformOptionsConf.json"), terraformOptionsConf)
```

And then you'll want two `destroy` steps (e.g., `destroy_infra`, `destroy_conf`), and each should use [LoadTestData](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/e323e9ffa190d559a0d7b048fa735945ec4d1cf9/modules/test-structure/save_test_data.go#L194) to get your data back and run `Destroy` on it:

```
defer test_structure.RunTestStage(t, "destroy_infra", func() {
  var terraformOptionsInfra *terraform.Options
  test_structure.LoadTestData(t, test_structure.FormatTestDataPath(terraformDir, "TerraformOptionsInfra.json"), terraformOptionsInfra)
  terraform.Destroy(t, terraformOptionsInfra)
})

defer test_structure.RunTestStage(t, "destroy_conf", func() {
  var terraformOptionsConf *terraform.Options
  test_structure.LoadTestData(t, test_structure.FormatTestDataPath(terraformDir, "TerraformOptionsConf.json"), terraformOptionsConf)
  terraform.Destroy(t, terraformOptionsConf)
})
```

Comment: Does that I mean I have to replace the two lines ```SaveTerraformOptions``` by ```SaveTestData``` ? Cause in that case I guess there will be some change also at the ```test_structure.RunTestStage```

Comment: Yes, you'll need to update the validate stage to use `LoadTestData`!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get it working.
Using @yevgeniy idea, I came up with following code.

```
    package test
    
    import (
                "fmt"
                 "time"
                "os"
                "testing"
                "net/http"
                "log"
                "io/ioutil"
    
                "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"
                "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/retry"
    
                test_structure "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/test-structure"
    )
    
    func configureTerraformOptions(t *testing.T, terraformDir string, tfModule string) (*terraform.Options) {
    
        awsRegion := os.Getenv("AWS_REGION")
    
        terraformOptions := &terraform.Options{
    
            TerraformDir: terraformDir,
            Targets: []string{tfModule},
            Vars: map[string]interface{}{
                "aws_region": awsRegion,
            },
        }
    
        return terraformOptions
    
    }
    
    func TestInfra(t *testing.T) {
        t.Parallel()
    
        terraformDir := test_structure.CopyTerraformFolderToTemp(t, "../", "tests/terraform")
    
        defer test_structure.RunTestStage(t, "destroy", func() {
            terraformOptionsInfra := configureTerraformOptions(t, terraformDir, "module.infra")
            terraformOptionsConf := configureTerraformOptions(t, terraformDir, "module.conf")
            terraform.Destroy(t, terraformOptionsConf)
            terraform.Destroy(t, terraformOptionsInfra)
        })
    
        test_structure.RunTestStage(t, "setup", func() {
            terraformOptionsInfra := configureTerraformOptions(t, terraformDir, "module.infra")
            terraformOptionsConf := configureTerraformOptions(t, terraformDir, "module.conf")
    
            test_structure.SaveTerraformOptions(t, terraformDir, terraformOptionsInfra)
    
            test_structure.SaveTerraformOptions(t, terraformDir, terraformOptionsConf)
    
            terraform.InitAndApply(t, terraformOptionsInfra)
            terraform.InitAndApply(t, terraformOptionsConf)
        })
    
        test_structure.RunTestStage(t, "validate", func() {
            terraformOptions := test_structure.LoadTerraformOptions(t, terraformDir)
             testHello(t, terraformOptions)

    })
}

func testHello(t *testing.T, terraformOptions *terraform.Options) {
   fmt.Printf("Hello")
}
```

I hope this can help other people.